# Why I can NOT set an existing win form within my win-based project application as a startup object?

Tags: winforms, properties, startup

in Application tab of project properties window and in startup objects combobox, I can NOT see my win forms in order to set one of them as startup object.

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with it. You do not see your forms in the combo box because the startup object of your application has to be an object which contains a `static void Main()` method.  A Form does not usually contain such a method.

Answer (score 8):

Open `Program.cs` file of your StartUp Project (project selected as StartUp project in solution) and change parameter of `Application.Run` to your desired form object. This might look like this:

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1()); // <-- this line decides which form will be opened at start
}
```

ps. it doesn't have to be `Program.cs` but it is by default, to be exact it is file which contains static class with static method `Main()`.

Comment: Thank you But what about using Visual Studio 2010 mechanism to set the startup object NOT programatically?

Comment: +1 for answering not the question, but what the OP actually wants to do, regardless of what he is asking.

Comment: @odiseh: You need to have the programmatic entry point available in order to use VS 2010 to set it. (What you are actually doing is setting a compile option)